# GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Unknown WKB type 337

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

I am coding a geo-based application with geodjango and postgis. I wrote the model and filled the first few points by hand from the admin interface. All worked fine, and I can even search by the nearest points. So the model and database are all working fine. Now I am trying to bulk filling the database from a script. Based on the answers I found here I am doing it first filling the longitude and the latitude columns then by executing

```
engine.execute("UPDATE listings_listing SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude), 4326)")
```

from a python script. The query executes without exceptions and the database seems filled with proper values. Here few examples

```
 longitude, latitude, location
-55.7385809,-34.7413717,"0101000020E6100000A279A5D189DE4BC008D79244E55E41C0"
-56.1645314,-34.9011127,"0101000020E610000022156B5D0F154CC0504134A9577341C0"
-56.4670779,-30.4264621,"0101000020E610000099976835C93B4CC0C57BC49E2C6D3EC0"
-55.760207,-34.774156,"0101000020E61000005B9885764EE14BC04700378B176341C0"
-56.2553815,-34.7901883,"0101000020E610000070404B57B0204CC04617E5E3246541C0"
-55.760336,-34.773944,"0101000020E610000059FCA6B052E14BC0BC77D498106341C0"
-57.0544726,-30.7552116,"0101000020E610000098C349F5F8864CC0518F238C55C13EC0"
-56.4739006,-30.4097107,"0101000020E610000003475DC6A83C4CC03F52E9CCE2683EC0"
```

Now when I try to make the first search by the nearest points i get

```
GEOS_ERROR: ParseException: Unknown WKB type 337
```

and from the logs of django

```
Error encountered checking Geometry returned from GEOS C function "GEOSWKBReader_read_r".
```

I googled the error but nothing. I checked possible NULL values in longitude and latitudes, but they are all fine. I suspect that I am missing a step.
Someone can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was the bulk filling with pandas. If you use the method `.to_sql()` of pandas with the parameter `if_exists='replace'`, than pandas drop the existing table and replace it completely breaking every schema. So before filling the geometry type column you must rebuild the geometry column in this way

```
ALTER TABLE listings_listing ADD COLUMN location geometry(Point, 4326);
```

and then

```
UPDATE listings_listing SET location = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326)
```

now everything works great!